# Creating an SNMP agent with Qt and C++

Tags: c++, qt, snmp, mib

I'm considering adding SNMP support to a simple daemon I wrote under linux.  My daemon is written in C++ and Qt5.

I'm looking for an easy way to add this support.  I found several MIB creation tools, the problem is writing the agent (or subagent).  I'd rather not code this in C, would anyone know of q Qt library that helps out?  I found mib2c which will create a skeleton in C (but I'd rather use C++ with Qt).

Comment: Hi, did you find something useful or did you manage to do something by yourself?

Comment: Not happy with what I found - code generators create boilerplates but still LOTS of work from there

Comment: Oh I see... Well then I think I'll just drop SNMP and write my own message exchange protocol based on UDP or TCP something. Thx anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [CIMPLE](https://github.com/LegalizeAdulthood/cimple), which I've forked on github from it's original website.  I've done some cleanup on github and I've attempted to contact the original authors, but they've never returned any of my emails which makes me wonder whether or not they intend to continue supporting the library.

Regardless, it does work and it plays fairly nicely with both Windows and Linux, which have very different styles of implementing SNMP agents.  If you google around for "WBEM" you will find some other libraries as well.  CIMPLE is the one we used at Fusion-io for SNMP support.  It supported C++ fairly well and uses a code generator to handle lots of the boiler plate stuff that's really boring to write and not specific to your application.